# Interface Instantiation ASP .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Interfaces cannot be instantiated but the return type of Context.Handler in asp .net is IHttpHandler which is an interface!

How is Context.Handler returning an object of an interface?

Comment: It's returning an instance of an object that implements the `IHttpHandler` interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not.  It's returning an instance of an class that implements that interface.  If you examine the return value while debugging, you can see the exact return type -- that return type can be ANY class that implements the interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply telling you that the return type must be of type `IHttpHandler`.

More concrete and controllable example:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public class Foo : IFoo { }
public class Bar : IFoo { }

public class Whatever
{
    public IFoo GetAFoo(bool thing)
    {
         if (thing)
            return new Foo();
         else
            return new Bar();
    }
}
```

Both `Foo` and `Bar` are implementing `IFoo`, so are valid returns for an `IFoo` return type.